# How do I allow for animals to breed, with a random chance of success, in my virtual zoo?

Tags: java

I have been tasked with allowing animals to breed in my zoo. If a male and female of the same animal are in the same enclosure then there is a random chance that they will have a baby. The basic layout of my zoo is an abstract animal class which is extended by a range of animals, such as lions. Each animal has a range of variables they inherit from the animal class, and one of these is a string gender variable. The gender is specified when the animal is created from its constructor. I have limited this variable so it can only take the strings "m" and "f". My zoo is modelled around a aMonthPasses() method.

I figure that I will have to make another method in my animal class which pairs up males and females together and then somehow there is a chance that they have a child that month but I have no clue how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can provide more details of my code if needed.

Animal class:

```
public abstract class Animal {   //cannot be instantiated
protected int age;
protected String gender;
protected String[] eats = new String[] {"steak", "celery", "hay", "fruit", "fish", "iceCream"};   //an array of strings
protected int health;
protected int lifeExpectancy;
protected Enclosure enclosure;

protected Animal(int age, String gender, String[] eats, int health, int lifeExpectancy) {   //animal constructor
    this.age = age;
    this.eats = eats;
    this.health = 10;   //base health for each animal will be 10
    this.lifeExpectancy = lifeExpectancy;
    if(gender.equals("m") || gender.equals("f)")) {        //this if statement will limit the gender variable to "m" or "f" for male or female
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}

protected int getAge() {
    return age;                //returns the age value
}

protected String getGender() {
    return gender;
    }
}
```

constructor in each individual animal:

```
private Bear(int age, String gender, String[] eats, int health, int lifeExpectancy) {
    super(age, gender, new String[]{"steak", "fish"}, health, lifeExpectancy);
    this.lifeExpectancy = 18;  //the bear has a life expectancy of 18 months
}`
```

Comment: Yes please post your code.

Comment: added my animal class code

Comment: i have a suggestion, make gender an enum,

Comment: How are the animals stored. Is it one big List of Type Animal. Or do you have a list of bears, lions...

Comment: a list of bears, lions...

Comment: Would the zoo control the breeding or wold each animal by chance find another animal to breed with?

Comment: the zoo would not influence it, I have a number of enclosures and as long as two of the same animals of different genders are in the same enclosure, they have a chance to breed each month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, let's define gender roles within pregnancy. Taking a few assumptions that animals must reach puberty before they can breed, have a maximum fertile age, etc, we can write something like:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public enum Gender implements BiFunction<Animal, Animal, Optional<Animal>> {
    MALE {
        @Override
        public Optional<Animal> apply(final Animal self,
                                      final Animal other) {
            // example - animal reaches sexual maturity at 2 - you should make this a property of animal
            return self.age > 2 ? other.gender.apply(other, self)
                                : Optional.empty();
        }
    },
    FEMALE {
        @Override
        public Optional<Animal> apply(final Animal self,
                                      final Animal other) {
            final Optional<Animal> child;
            // must be at least 2 to get pregnant, infertile 3 years before death.  Again, just examples
            if (self.age > 2 && self.age < self.lifeExpectancy - 3
                && self.health > 5) {
                final int chance = new Random().nextInt(10);
                child = (chance == 3 || chance == 6 || chance == 9) ? Optional.of(self.reproduce())
                                                                    : Optional.empty();
            } else {
                child = Optional.empty();
            }
            return child;
        }
    };
}
```

We then change Animal to use the `Gender` enum in place of a `String`.

Enclosures can contain many different types of animals, so we need to distinguish by species and gender.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Enclosure {
    private final List<Animal> animals = new LinkedList<>();

    public void add(final Animal animal) {
        this.animals.add(animal);
    }

    public Set<Class<? extends Animal>> getSpecies() {
        final Set<Class<? extends Animal>> species = new HashSet<>();
        for (Animal animal : animals) {
            species.add(animal.getClass());
        }
        return species;
    }

    public List<Animal> getMales(final Class<? extends Animal> species) {
        return byGender(species,
                        Gender.MALE);
    }

    public List<Animal> getFemales(final Class<? extends Animal> species) {
        return byGender(species,
                        Gender.FEMALE);
    }

    private List<Animal> byGender(final Class<? extends Animal> species,
                                  final Gender gender) {
        return animals.stream()
                      .filter(animal -> animal.gender == gender)
                      .filter(animal -> animal.getClass().equals(species))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

I'm not a big fan of filtering by class type, so you might want to add an abstract `public String getSpecies()` method to `Animal`.

Finally, we need a way for animals to make little animals - when they love each other very much, of course - so we need another abstract method in `Animal`.

```
public abstract Animal reproduce();
```

Within, for example, your Bear class you could implement this as

```
public Animal reproduce() {
    // you'll need to randomize gender and health
    return gender == Gender.FEMALE ? new Bear(...) : null;
}
```

Within your main app, you can then get all the individual species with an enclosure, then mate the males and females.  You will need to allow for, I guess, at most  single pregnancy per female per month and so on.  I haven't don't that here, so you can't copy it directly for your homework :-)

```
Enclosure enclosure = new Enclosure();
// enclosure is populated with animals

// each month...
final Set<Class<? extends Animal>> allSpecies = enclosure.getSpecies();
for (Class<? extends Animal> species : allSpecies) {
    final List<Animal> females = enclosure.getFemales(species);
    final List<Animal> males = enclosure.getFemales(species);
    for (Animal male : males) {
        for (Animal female : females) {
            final Optional<Animal> maybeOffspring = male.gender.apply(male,
                                                                    female);
            maybeOffspring.ifPresent(enclosure::add);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a starting point, let's imagine some utility class with this method :

```
public double evaluateBabyProbability(Animal a, Animal b){

    // animals are of different kind, no chance
    if(!a.getClass().equals(b.getClass()))
    return 0d;

    // animals have different enclosures, no chance
    if(!a.getEnclosure().equals(b.getEnclosure()))
    return 0d;

    // animals have the same gender, no chance
    if(a.getGender().equals(b.getGender()))
    return 0d;

    // Here, evaluate the probability based on any variables you need (age, month, health...)


    // return result

    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I came up with the following but now it doesn't like the fact that I have a double as a return type.

Comment: posted it as an answer as didnt know how to comment with code format

Comment: "it doesn't like" : what happens exactly ?

Comment: it gives me the error "method must return a result of type double" and suggests that I change the return type to void or add a return statement. I am using eclipse.

Comment: Add a default return statement at the end of the method, return 0d; for instance

Comment: Or a classic ``throw null;`` statement (throws a NPE) :P

Answer (score 0):

```
public double evaluateBabyProbability(Animal a, Animal b){

        if(!a.getClass().equals(b.getClass()))   // animals are of different kind, no chance
        return 0;

        if(!a.getEnclosure().equals(b.getEnclosure()))  // animals have different enclosures, no chance
        return 0;

        if(a.getGender().equals(b.getGender()))  // animals have the same gender, no chance
        return 0;

        if(!a.getGender().equals(b.getGender()))  //animals of different gender have chance of breeding of 0.5 each month
        return 0.5;
        }

    private Object getEnclosure() {
        return enclosure;
    }
```

Comment: Oh and you may consider returning 0d and 0.5d, to tell the program that they are double values .

Answer (score 0):

Sweet task. That whould be my approach on this.

```
public class Zoo{
    abstract class Animal{
        protected String gender;
        protected String name;
        public Animal(String _gender, String _name){
            gender = _gender;
            name = _name;
        }
        public String getGender(){return gender;}
        public String toString(){return gender + name;}
    }
    class Lion extends Animal{
        public Lion(String _gender, String _name){
            super(_gender, _name);
        }
    }
    class Hippo extends Animal{
        public Hippo(String _gender, String _name){
            super(_gender, _name);
        }
    }
    ArrayList<Animal> animals;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    final int BREED_CHANCE = 1; // for test let them breed always

    public Zoo(){

        animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        animals.add(new Lion("m", "Lion1"));
        animals.add(new Lion("m", "Lion2"));
        animals.add(new Lion("f", "Lion3"));
        animals.add(new Lion("f", "Lion4"));
        animals.add(new Lion("f", "Lion5"));

        animals.add(new Hippo("m", "Hippo1"));
        animals.add(new Hippo("m", "Hippo2"));
        animals.add(new Hippo("f", "Hippo3"));      
    }

    public ArrayList<Animal> findAllPossibleMaleBreedPartners(Animal femaleAnimal){
        ArrayList<Animal> result = new ArrayList<>();
        // find an animal
        for(Animal animal : animals){
            // that is male and same species as female Animal
            if(animal.getGender().equals("m") &&
                animal.getClass() == femaleAnimal.getClass()){
                // then its a possible breed partner
                result.add(animal);
            }
        }
        return result;      
    }

    public void breed(){
        // for each Animal
        for(Animal female : animals){
            // if its female
            if(female.getGender().equals("f")){
                // find all possible male breed partners
                ArrayList<Animal> partners = findAllPossibleMaleBreedPartners(female);
                // if there are any and chance is given
                if(!partners.isEmpty() && rnd.nextInt(BREED_CHANCE) == 0){
                    //pick one of them
                    Animal male = partners.get(rnd.nextInt(partners.size()));
                    // and let them breed
                    System.out.println(female + " & " + male + " making a baby!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void aMonthPasses(){
        breed();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
            zoo.aMonthPasses();
    }
}
```